# iTerm command click to open with Atom

Tags: macos, iterm2

I am trying to figure out how to change iTerm function when <kbd>CMD</kbd>+Clicking on a file in an iTerm window to have it open in my default editor, Atom.

Currently, the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+click function in iTerm opens files in Sublime. I have the function <kbd>CMD</kbd>+Click set to open with the default app (within iTerm preferences). I have also ensured that this file type is configured to always open with Atom (in the file's info screen from Finder).

[image]

If I click the file from finder, it opens with Atom, not sublime text. The only clue I have is that maybe iTerm won't recognize Atom as an editor. If I go to iTerm Preferences > Profiles > Advanced and change the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+Click to open with what Editor, only sublime 3 is available in the list of editors to choose from.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note: iTerm2's new release of Build 3.0.0 adds "Atom" to the list of options for the "Open with editor..." dropdown as pictured above. You'll find it now in Preferences under Profiles -> Advanced -> Semantic History.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inside Atom, go to the `Atom` menu and choose `Install Shell Commands`.  This ensures you can call Atom from iTerm.

In that same iTerm preferences screen, change the first select list to `Run command...` and paste the following into the text field that appears: `/usr/local/bin/atom -n \1:\2`.  That tells the atom command line tool to open the clicked file (\1) at the line number specified (\2).

Comment: Hi! Leaving the "-n" out from your suggestion makes it open in an existing window (which is what I prefer). Unfortunately this makes atom fail to recognize the column number (it goes to the correct line though). Any ideas on this?

Comment: Any chance you can add the solution for iTerm2 to your answer please!? Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Atom is an option in the 'Open with editor...' select list now.  This answer is no longer useful.

Comment: I've tried this for Android Studio (which isn't included in the list of editors) but it did not work. I get a "can not open file" error, despite setting up shell commands for the right path in the IDE. Anyone got that working before?

Answer (score 24):

(I use this one. For some reason the iTerm option "Open with default app" doesn't work, but the command "$ open whatever" works like a charm, so I've just set that command.

[image]

Comment: This seems to work well especially if one has multiple versions of same application installed. For eg: VS Code and VS Code Insider. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: There is also an "Open with editor" option now where one can select VS Code 